# Copy from one table in a database, to an exact copy of the table on another database on the same SQL server using a trigger

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Fairly new to SQL. I am trying to copy a tables data from one database to a table exactly the same on another database within the same SQL Server instance using an on insert trigger.

If I run it as a standalone query:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @IDTSMAX AS INT 

SET @IDTSMAX = (SELECT MAX(IDTS)
                FROM [LabReports].[dbo].[TruckQualityLAB])

INSERT INTO [DryPlant].[dbo].[TruckQualityLAB] (BOL, Quality, Location, Product, Date, IDTS)
    SELECT 
        BOL, Quality, Location, Product, Date, IDTS 
    FROM 
        [LabReports].[dbo].[TruckQualityLAB] 
    WHERE
        @IDTSMAX = IDTS
```

it works just fine, but if I create it as a trigger, it fails and the insert to either table doesn't occur. The primary table on LabReports is populated by 8 insert triggers from other tables.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TruckQualityLABUPDATE] 
ON [LabReports].[dbo].[TruckQualityLAB]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @IDTSMAX AS INT
    SET @IDTSMAX = (SELECT MAX(IDTS)
                    FROM [LabReports].[dbo].TruckQualityLAB])

    INSERT INTO [DryPlant].[dbo].[TruckQualityLAB](BOL, Quality, Location, Product, Date, IDTS)
        SELECT 
            BOL, Quality, Location, Product, Date, IDTS 
        FROM 
            [LabReports].[dbo].[TruckQualityLAB] 
        WHERE
            @IDTSMAX = IDTS
END
```

I need this data copied so I can then update truck records with correct quality for reporting etc.

Any ideas why this is not working as a trigger? Everything I read says it should work.

EDIT.
The TruckQualityLAB table is updated randomly, from 2 different labs using a web interface, so it is possible for 2 or 3 records to be entered within seconds of each other, since this table is populated from insert triggers on 8 other product tables.( On Insert create row in truckqualitylab table). I then want to use this consolidated table in the other DB to update records with quality values. These have to be LIVE for the web pages to report on demand.

Comment: You need to check out the `Inserted` pseudo table - this contains the newly inserted rows - these need to be stored to the other table

Comment: What about updated rows??

Comment: @marc_s, correct, my bad, deleting :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check out the Inserted pseudo table - this contains the newly inserted rows - these need to be stored to the other table

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TruckQualityLABUPDATE] 
ON [LabReports].[dbo].[TruckQualityLAB]
AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO [DryPlant].[dbo].[TruckQualityLAB](BOL, Quality, Location, Product, Date, IDTS)
        SELECT 
            BOL, Quality, Location, Product, Date, IDTS 
        FROM 
            Inserted
END
```

Comment: So, this Should take the latest inserted information, and insert into the other table without taking all records or needing the MAXID condition? When I tried this, it did the same thing and failed to update ALL tables when trigger was active, including the original product table updated from the web portal. (Removed IDTS since that is a identifier also but didn't work)

Comment: @AdrianWalker: yes exactly - this trigger just copies all the rows that your `INSERT` statement (whether that's 1 row, or 1000) and insert those values into the `DryPlant` database

Comment: Noticed that on the table, if I have the trigger enabled, every insert trigger fails, however on the truckqualitylab table, the identifier is incrementing every time even though jobs fail and no record is being recorded. BOL Quality Location Product Date                  IDTS
P181315 94.8       Mine 100M-AZ    2018-01-10 08:33:51.310 1
P181308 96.4       Mine 100M-AZ    2018-01-10 08:34:47.533 2
P181252 94.9       Mine 1220-AZ    2018-01-10 08:47:51.047 3
P181359 95.2       Mine 4070-AZ    2018-01-10 09:16:20.490 5
P181340 98.1       Mine 3050-AZ    2018-01-10 13:43:55.340 12

Comment: Noticed that on the table, if I have the trigger enabled, every insert trigger fails, however on the truckqualitylab table, the identifier is incrementing every time even though jobs fail and no record is being recorded. even tried making another trigger that updated a column first, then had this trigger fire on update rather than insert. same issue, no record created but identifier incremented by 1.

Comment: Thank you.These solutions work just fine. trigger was failing due to trying to convert a Nvarchar to int. Something so simple.